# PostgreSQL: count occurrence of true values in columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, aggregate-functions

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE trips(
     trip_id int,
     true_foot boolean,
     true_bike boolean,
     true_bus boolean,
     true_car boolean,
     true_metro boolean
)

INSERT INTO trips (trip_id,true_foot,true_bike,true_bus,true_car,true_metro) 
VALUES 
  (563097,'t','f','f','f','f'),
  (596303,'f','f','f','t','f'),
  (595648,'f','f','f','t','f'),
  (566061,'t','f','f','f','f'),
  (566753,'t','f','f','f','f'),
  (561179,'t','f','f','f','f'),
  (535519,'f','f','f','f','f'),
  (548460,'t','f','f','f','f'),
  (543477,'f','f','f','t','f'),
  (540797,'t','f','f','f','f')
```

Only one column has true value in a row (or none). Then I want to count all true values for foot, bike, bus, etc...

```
SELECT 
 COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE true_foot IS TRUE ) AS 'walk',
 COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE true_bike IS TRUE ) AS 'bike',
 COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE true_bus IS TRUE) AS 'bus',
 COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE true_car IS TRUE) AS 'car',
 COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE true_metro IS TRUE) AS 'metro'
     
FROM trips

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "'walk'"
LINE 3:  COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE true_foot IS TRUE ) AS 'walk',
```

Comment: Remove the single quotes.

Comment: Ah, thank you. SQL error log is often doesn't give precise hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single quotes should only be used for string and date constants.  You don't need them, so remove them.

Also, `is true` is actually redundant.  So:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE true_foot) AS walk,
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE true_bike) AS bike,
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE true_bus) AS bus,
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE true_car) AS car,
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE true_metro) AS metro
FROM trips;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, will definitely remove the `IS TRUE`

Comment: Ah, my bad, I was considering ease of readability, (not aware of performance).

Comment: Sure `EXPLAIN` shows that this is nearly 3x faster, thanks for the information.

Answer (score 3):

I like to use `SUM()` for this. You just need to convert the booleans to integer values (`true` becomes `1`, `false` becomes `0`).

```
SELECT 
    SUM( (true_food)::int )  AS walk,
    SUM( (true_bike)::int )  AS bike,
    SUM( (true_bus)::int )   AS bus,
    SUM( (true_car)::int )   AS car,
    SUM( (true_metro)::int ) AS metro
FROM trips
```